# Displaying content from a .txt file using a cURL

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to display content from a txt file on a remote server using a cURL if the function file_get_contents is not turned on on their server. Right now, I have it set up as:

```
    $updatelog ='http://www.linktoremotsite.com/updatelog.txt';

    if(function_exists('file_get_contents')){
    $log = file_get_contents($updatelog);
}else{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $updatelog);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $log = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}

echo '<div>' . $log . '</div>';
```

and the file_get_contents works fine, but for those that don't have that enabled on their site, I like them to be able to use a curl to see the contents of the .txt file. But I can't seem to get the contents of the .txt file to display.

The .txt file does have some HTML in it for the file_get_contents to display neatly, but not much and I like to keep that with the curl if possible.

Comment: Have you got any error? try with `if( !curl_exec($ch) ) {  print_r(curl_error($ch)); }`

Comment: @jogesh_pi After trying a few different ways to see if I could get anything to display, I had to do echo print_r(curl_error($ch)); and that displayed a 1, everything else just showed blank.